# No gradients provided for any variable - optimizer error

Tags: python

I'm computing as follows:

```
     #Compute the cost
     cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - out))

     minimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Upon running `minimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)`, I receive this error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'parameters:0' shape=(15,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'weights:0' shape=(6,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Mean_1:0", dtype=float32).
```

Where is this path wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: The problem causing the error message is that your model function dose not use any tensorflow variables.

Meaning: The only TF.variable that you are defining is w, which is not used in the model function. Thus, there are no wights in the model that tensorflow can optimize with regard to the loss function.  If you want tensorflow to optimize the coefficients, use the variable w instead of the constant coefficients c in your model definition and make sure they have the same size.

Also, you are using non tensorflow functions in your model definition like the append function instead of tf.append. This adds to the problem.

There are a number of more problems in your code. For example, you double defined the global variable initializer and the session.

I guess the basic problem is that you did not yet understand the basic structure of the low level tensorflow API. Explicitly, the concept of the graph and session definition. You first need to define a graph containing the complete definition of your model and using only tensorflow functions. Only afterwards you start a session in which you initialize the wights and start to train it.